# SQL Select outter Join and Group By and IFNULL ( COUNT ) HELP =x

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, outer-join

I have this database and i was wondering to create a great select but is too hard for me I guess I tried so many ways and I get really close, but i cant go longer.

Database

```
Table -> Candidato | IdCandidato(int) | idNome(varchar)

Table -> Voto  | idVoto(int) | Candidato_idCandidato(int) | DiaVotacao(date)
```

i am creating a web voting system and need i greate select to complet my graphics to show the total voting for each day for each candidate.

```
Candidato = candidate | voto = vote | diaVotacao = voting day (english translation)
```

I need i response like this:

```
|VotingDay---------|-----Candidate1----------|-----Candidate2------|--Candidate3

|2014-05-14-------|---13(total votes)---------|------------4------------|-----------10|

|2014-05-15-------|---18(total votes)---------|------------0------------|------------8|
```

and so far i got this:

```
|VotingDay---------|-----TOTAL Votes----------|-----Name------|

|2014-05-14-------|---13(total votes)---------|-Candidate1

|2014-05-14-------|---18(total votes)---------|-Candidate2

|2014-05-15-------|---10(total votes)---------|-Candidate1

|2014-05-15-------|----8(total votes)---------|-Candidate2
```

I used the following code:

> SELECT voto.DiaVotacao, IFNULL(COUNT(voto.Candidato_idCandidato),0) as Votos, candidato.Nome
>   FROM candidato LEFT OUTER JOIN voto ON voto.Candidato_idCandidato=candidato.idCandidato 
>   GROUP BY voto.DiaVotacao, voto.Candidato_idCandidato

Note that i want the count of the votes for each candidate for everey day and if there is no votes apear the number 0 to indicate no votes
did u guys understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate the full list of candidates and days and *then* do the `left outer join`.  You can get the list of days from the `votos` table.

Note that when you use `count(<column>)`, it will return `0` if all the values are `NULL`.  There is no need for `ifull()` or `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT d.DiaVotacao, COUNT(v.Candidato_idCandidato) as Votos, c.Nome
FROM candidato c cross join
     (SELECT DISTINCT v.DiaVotacao FROM voto v
     ) d LEFT OUTER JOIN
     voto v
     ON v.Candidato_idCandidato = c.idCandidato and
        v.DiaVotacao = d.DiaVotacao
GROUP BY d.DiaVotacao, v.Candidato_idCandidato;
```

Comment: i'm so familiarized with all this parameters you show great wisdow, but when you refer v.diavotacao i got a error:
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'v.DiaVotacao' in 'field list'

i tried to replace with voto.diavotacao but i have got the same results reptly the dates is not getting distinct, perhaps the v table resulting from the distinct should be declare before their mention? i'm doing something wrong?